# getElementsByClassName wont work for overlay

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to switch OVERLAY on button click.
After adding these two buttons under same class, and calling this function, JS simply won't get it done.
I am not sure what is the problem in :

```
document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay' )
```

or somewhere else?

If I leave it as `document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' )` and in html switch to `id` instead of `class`, it works only for one element.

Kinda stuck here.

```
<p><button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
<p><button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay2</button></p>
```

and js function:

```
    (function() {
    var triggerBttn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay' ),
        overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
        closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

    function toggleOverlay() {
        if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
            classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
            classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
            var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
            };
            if( support.transitions ) {
                overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndTransitionFn();
            }
        }
        else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
            classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
        }
    }

    triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
    closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

Comment: `triggerBttn` is going to be an array though... it's getElementS, not getElement. You'll need to check the size of the array and make sure it has elements

Comment: you mean like triggerBttn [] = ... ? it is getElements :\

Answer (score 1):

`triggerBttn` is an array. Here you need to use it like an array...like below

```
var triggerBttn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay' ),


for(var i=0; i < triggerBttn.length ; i++)
{
  triggerBttn[i].addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
}
```

Comment: so even after adding [] like `triggerBttn[]`, so it looks like `var triggerBttn[] = document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay' ),` i added your loop under it after `,` . still bugging. do i have to define multiple class usages in `document.getElementsByClassName('class1 class2')` or ?

Comment: you don't have to add []. Just take it as simple 'var triggerBttn' and use it under for loop as shown in my answer...it should work

Comment: tried, but its still the same. ive been using this overlay http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/ for my purpose, maybe that helps :]